# Getting data from emails in SAS

Tags: email, sas

I have emails that contain data in an unstructured format. I need to extract this data from these emails. Is there a way to do this in SAS? 
Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you saved the emails as text files that SAS can read?  If not then you probably first need a method to do that.  If you have, then show example of what a file looks like and explain what information you want to extract from it. And show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Do you want to read the mail directly from the server ? What POP or IMAP mail server ? Some other mail server ?

Comment: @Tom I first need to convert the emails to text format. Is there a way other than manual converting them all, as there is over 10000 emails?